# LAN Development in XNA

Tags: c#, networking, xna, vmware

I'm looking at developing a LAN-Only game as part of my coursework at university, however only own 1 computer.

Reading around the internet, it seems to be possible to develop such a game by utilising a vmware image and installing all the appropriate pre-reqs on that, then using

```
NetworkSession.Create(NetworkSessionType.SystemLink, 1, 4);
```

to create a network instance on the VM/Devel machine, and then running

```
  using (AvailableNetworkSessionCollection networkSessions =    NetworkSession.Find(NetworkSessionType.PlayerMatch, 1, null))
```

to try and find the newly created session.

So far however, I can't seem to find the other computer.

I've tried networking on both NAT and bridged (as unsure which is correct(?)) to no avail.

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Just loopback to yourself on the same computer, no need to run VMWare. Run a server on one port and connect to it.

If you really want to use VMWare I always choose bridged networking myself, but I really don't think you need VMWare.